# VS me cambia el codigo en React Native

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio

Estoy aprendiendo a programar,por lo que soy un ignorante en todo, si es una estupidez siento la pregunta. En fin, el problema es que cuando guardo visual studio me cambia el codigo (adjunto imagen).Es decir, como se ve en la imagen me cambia el texto en text y en view y cklaro da error, tengo que decir que es al guardar. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya se que era, estuve indagando por foros ingleses y me di cuenta de que era una extension de Visual Studio JS Formatter. Por si a alguien le ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya se que era, estuve indagando por foros ingleses y me di cuenta de que era una extension de Visual Studio JS Formatter. Por si a alguien le ayuda.